# Order of an element in a finite Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Theorem 2.4.5 in Herstein's book says if $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ then $a^n = e$ for all $a$ in $G$.

Is this a typo? I know the order of each element must divide $n$, but must it equal the order of the group?

Comment: "Is this a typo?" Presumably Herstein *proves* this theorem, in which case you should know that it isn't a typo. You can't prove a mere typo.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sometimes it's hard enough to follow through a proof *knowing* there aren't any typos.

Comment: I'd change the title, since this is not about a typo, but about a perfectly correct (and almost trivial) result that the OP thought was a typo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not a typo: the order of an element need not be equal to the order of the group (think about e.g. the unit element $e$), it's enough that it divides it in order to obtain $a^{|G|}=e$:

Say, order of $a\in G$ is $k$, and $k$ divides $n=|G|$, i.e. $n=kq$ for some $q\in\Bbb Z$. Then we have
$$a^n=a^{kq}=(a^k)^q=e^q=e$$

Comment: Could I just suggest a correction to your English? It would be clearer to say that the order  of the element "need not be equal to the order of the group" rather than "must not be equal", which suggests that it is definitely unequal to it!

Answer (score 9):

The text is not saying that $n$, the order of the group, is the order of $a$.  The text is saying that $n$ is a number that *could be different than the order of $a$* that is *also* such that $a^n =e$.

By Legrange theorem, you *know* that $|a|$ divides $n$ so $n = k*|a|$ for some integer $k$.

So $a^n = a^{k|a|} = (a^{|a|})^k= e^k =e$.

That shouldn't be surprising.  Although it is easy to see how the statement could be misinterpreted.

(Note: It's very easy to prove  $a^j =e$ if and only if $j$ is multiple of the order of $a$. So this is just pointing out that $n$ *is* a multiple of the order of $a$.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a typo: $ a^n = e $ does not mean that the order of $a$ is $n$, only that it is at most $n$ (actually, it must be a divisor of $n$).